# How to Pivot on caption?

Tags: t-sql, pivot

I am trying to pivot rows into columns with Tsql and also eliminate Nulls.  How do I do this?  My current query:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#test_data') IS NOT NULL drop table #test_data

create table #test_data (
question_caption varchar(max),
[0] varchar(max),
[1] varchar(max),
[2] varchar(max),
[3] varchar(max))

insert #test_data values('q1','abc',Null,Null,Null)
insert #test_data values('q2',Null,'def',Null,Null)
insert #test_data values('q3',Null,Null,'ghi',Null)
insert #test_data values('q4',Null,Null,Null,'jkl')

select * from #test_data
pivot (
    Max([0])
    For question_caption in ([0],[1],[2],[3])
) as PivotTable
```

Output:

```
question_caption    0   1   2   3
q1  abc NULL    NULL    NULL
q2  NULL    def NULL    NULL
q3  NULL    NULL    ghi NULL
q4  NULL    NULL    NULL    jkl
```

What I want:

```
q1   q2   q3   q4
abc  def  ghi  jkl
```

How can I achieve this?  The above query has the error:
Msg 265, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The column name "0" specified in the PIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the PIVOT argument.

I have tried multiple Pivot examples, but all of them have resulted in one error or another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with a simple `max case`:

```
select  [q1]=max(case when question_caption = 'q1' then [0] else null end),
        [q2]=max(case when question_caption = 'q2' then [1] else null end),
        [q3]=max(case when question_caption = 'q3' then [2] else null end),
        [q4]=max(case when question_caption = 'q4' then [3] else null end)
from    #test_data
```

or the pivot:

```
select  [q1], [q2], [q3], [q4]
from    (   select  question_caption, 
                    coalesce([0],[1],[2],[3]) 
            from    #test_data
        ) s (c, v)
pivot   (max(v) for c in ([q1], [q2], [q3], [q4])) p
```